# AngularJS Directive - Adding class to created 'div' element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to create a custom directive for my AngularJS project

**Here's what I have so far :**

```
.directive('testDirective', [

    function () {

        return {
            restrict: "EA",
            replace: false,
            transclude: false,

            link: function ($scope, el, attrs) {
                var param = {};

                param.className = attrs.customClass || 'default-class';
                param.distinctClassName = attrs.distinctClass || 'added-class';

                el.addClass(param.distinctClassName); // this works? :|

                var createdDiv = null;

                createdDiv = createdDiv || document.createElement('div');
                createdDiv.className = param.className; // this works...
                createdDiv.addClass(param.distinctClassName); // this doesn't work? :/
            }
        };
    }
]);
```

For now, this a very simple directive, but it will grow larger. I'm creating an element dynamically because I want to use it as a modal box, and I will append a div to the body.

I want to add a different class while keeping the original class to have all the default styling.

**Here's what's happening:**

Using `<test-directive custom-class="first" distinct-class="second" />` in the template

- Getting the parameters is working **- Good**
- Adding the classes to the directive element (test-directive) is working **- Good**
- Creating the div is working **- Good**
- Changing the className on the newly created div is working **- Good**
- Adding a class to the newly created div doesn't work... **- NOT GOOD**

Now, can anyone tell me why I can't add class but can change it directly? I know I must be forgetting something... but can't figure out what !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`createdDiv.addClass(param.distinctClassName);` does not work because it is a DOM element, it is not a jqlite wrapped angular element. And `addClass` is a function added on the jq wrapper and not available on the DOM element.

You would need to do:

```
angular.element(createdDiv).addClass(param.distinctClassName);
```

and `el.addClass(param.distinctClassName)` works because the element is an angular element (`jq[lite]` wrapped DOM element).

Leaving apart this issue, you could easily have a template for your directive and use `ng-class` bound to a scope property and you can get away from doing all these manually.